# What is the greatest value of $n$ such that $n < 100$ and $a_n$ is a power of $2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Problem**

> A sequence is defined by $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 4$ and $a_n = 4(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})$ for $n > 2$. What is the greatest value of $n$ such that $n < 100$ and $a_n$ is a power of $2$?

I tried doing a few terms but I couldn't get any real pattern. I saw that $a_5 = 128$ was a power of $2$ but no others.

Comment: If you tried a few more terms, you would get that $a_9 = 2^{12}$ and $a_{17} = 2^{21}$.

Comment: What does this say?

Comment: You also missed that $a_3$ is a power of $2$. With @JimmyK4542's values, a pattern should be clear.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know a bit about the theory of linear recurrence relations:

The characteristic polynomial for the recurrence $a_n = 4a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}$ is $\lambda^2 = 4\lambda-4$.

Since the characteristic polynomial has a double root at $\lambda = 2$, the general solution (i.e. ignoring the initial conditions) is of the form $a_n = (An+B) \cdot 2^n$ for some constants $A$ and $B$.

If you use the initial conditions $a_1 = 0$ and $a_2 = 4$, you will get the equations $A+B = 0$ and $4A+2B = 4$. Solve these to get $A = 1$ and $B = -1$.

Therefore, the solution is $a_n = (n-1) \cdot 2^n$. Now, finding the largest value of $n < 100$ such that $a_n$ is a power of $2$ should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the recurrence by standard methods gives
$$a_n=(n-1)2^n\ .$$
So you are looking for the largest $n<100$ such that $n-1$ is a power of $2$.  That's $n=65$.